# Accessing TLS 1.3 Website from Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, tls1.3

I am having Windows Server 2012 R2 and I need to access a website whose SSL Certificate is using TLS 1.3 (Screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot]

But I get this error in my browser (IE 11)

**This page can’t be displayed

Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to [WEBSITE]  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator.**

Is there a way to access this website in IE 11 on Windows Server 2012 R2 ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, no. There is no way currently because IE 11 does not support TLS1.3.
Please try to use another browser.

Last updated on : 2022-06-30

Browser Compatibility:

TLS 1.3 on IE is fully supported on None of the versions, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 5.5-11 IE versions.

TLS 1.3 on Edge is fully supported on 79-103, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 12-18 Edge versions.

TLS 1.3 on Firefox is fully supported on 63-104, partially supported on 60-62, and not supported on 2-59 Firefox versions.

TLS 1.3 on Chrome is fully supported on 70-106, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 4-69 Chrome versions.

TLS 1.3 on Safari is fully supported on 14.1-16, partially supported on 12.1-13, and not supported on 3.2-12 Safari versions.

TLS 1.3 on Opera is fully supported on 57-87, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 9.5-56 Opera versions.

TLS 1.3 on Safari on iOS is fully supported on 12.2-16, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 3.2-12 Safari on iOS versions.

TLS 1.3 on Android Browser is fully supported on 97-103, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 2.3-4 Android Browser versions.

TLS 1.3 on Opera Mobile is fully supported on 64-64, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 10-12 Opera Mobile versions.

TLS 1.3 on Chrome for Android is fully supported on 97-103, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on below 97 Chrome for Android versions.

TLS 1.3 on Firefox for Android is fully supported on 95-101, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on below 95 Firefox for Android versions.

TLS 1.3 on Samsung Internet is fully supported on 10.1-17, partially supported on None of the versions, and not supported on 4-9.2 Samsung Internet versions.